# Eclipse, can't load from network drive

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to open the AOSP source which is located on a laptop that is connected to my router via ethernet (running ubuntu server) from my windows laptop using eclipse (I copied .classpath to the root dir of the AOSP source) This is the location I enter in "Create New Java Project":

```
\\192.168.0.109\BuildServer\Settings
```

However, when I click finish, the progressbar shows at the bottom but Eclipse hangs and the progressbar remains at 0 forever...

does anyone know how I can fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Map the location to a local drive and use it via the drive letter, or better yet, copy the sources locally since they'll be accessed frequently.